# bxslider cutting images in half on first view

Tags: javascript

I got bxslider to work right out of the gate, and it seems like a great tool.  I am using the distribution untouched, including style sheet, however, the first image loads and displays fine, but the second image, and subsequent images, get chopped in half vertically and are aligned right.  This occurs only on the first course through the images, and if the munged image is displayed a second time, it appears correctly.

Some searching through StackOverflow and other forums led me down the path of fixing the width and height of the image, either in the  tag, the .bx-wrapper{} styles or to alter .bxslider{}, removing the margin.  None of these fixes have worked for that problem, but the problems weren't exactly the same as I am experiencing.

Has anyone seen this problem?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you provide the relevant parts of your code? HTML and JS, so we can reproduce the problem and see what options you used so we can help you. Also, a screen capture of your issue might help (or even better, a live demo). Oh, and just curious, do all of your images have the same size?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   mode: 'fade',
  auto: true,
  controls: true,
  infiniteLoop: true,
  speed: 1000
});
  });
</script>`

Comment: The solution to the problem was to use an unordered list, rather than <span> or <div> for the images.  In the bxslider FAQ (http://bxslider.com/faqs) where it offers a set up using <div> tags as a "completely legit slider setup." This is what led me astray.